# Program/method to repair a partially unreadable file from a backup copy

Tags: files, backup, btrfs, file-copy

I have a partially damaged file on an integrity-verifying filesystem (btrfs):

```
$ pv -c \{30939216-15e2-4563-b77e-2ab8687ec333\}.vdi >/dev/null
pv: {30939216-15e2-4563-b77e-2ab8687ec333}.vdi: read failed: Input/output error
3.41GiB 0:00:00 [5.25GiB/s] [=====================================================================>                                                                                                 ] 42%
```

I have an intact backup of this file, but it is very slow to access:

```
$ pv ~/mnt/borg/able-2022-10-05T12:00:21+04:00/arch/home/intelfx/VirtualBox\ VMs/Windows\ 10/Snapshots/\{30939216-15e2-4563-b77e-2ab8687ec333\}.vdi >/dev/null
1.3MiB 0:00:30 [430KiB/s] [>                                                                                                                                                                      ]  0% ETA 51:55:23
^C
```

Btrfs "knows" which pieces of the file are damaged — it returns I/O errors if I try to read damaged extents.

---

What would be the simplest way to repair the file from the backup copy, doing as little network I/O as possible? Bonus points for restoring the file in-place, minimizing the amount of overwritten data as well.

I thought about doing a ddrescue dance, but it feels fragile:

1. `ddrescue broken_file temp_file map_file` (save the `map_file`, discard the `temp_file`)
2. `ddrescue --retrim backup_file broken_file map_file` (reuse the `map_file`)

Maybe there is a simpler way I'm missing, or a tool specifically made for this purpose?

Comment: (Note that ddrescue dance that I mention does not even work as described — btrfs prevents writes into extents with errors. I guess I could punch a hole in the file, replacing the damaged extent, and only then perform the final ddrescue, but the process becomes even more brittle.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use ddrescue for this:

```
ddrescue damaged_file temp temp.map
ddrescue working_file temp temp.map --retrim
mv temp working_file
```

This would work without any special file system specific tools or root user access